# Replace Single Quotes with Apostrophe in String (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

My users sometimes enter, instead of apostrophe (`'`), symbols that look like apostrophe (`‘`), which causes some problems with database.

I tried to replace them with `gsub` like so:

```
result.gsub(/\‘/, "'")
result.gsub(/‘/, "'")
```

Neither of these options work - getting the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
  return result.gsub(/\‘/, "'").gsub("’", "'")
                          ^
```

Are they reserved by Ruby? How do I replace them?

Comment: which ruby version do you use?

Comment: 1.9.2 - because Heroku uses it

Comment: result = "‘helle’"
result.gsub(/\‘/, "'").gsub("’", "'")
invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'. it must be a encoding problem.

Comment: yep, was encoding. thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your text editor doesn't support UTF-8 characters like `‘` directly, you can escape them this way:

```
"\u2018"
```

So in your example, it would be:

```
result.gsub(/\u2018/, "'")
```

Comment: If you want to get left and right quote strings you must do this instead myString.gsub(/[\u2018\u2019]/, "'"). Recently had to do this with a Windows XML export for a Rails app.

Comment: from where you got the mapping for `‘` is `"\u2018"` ? I need the same for `'ô'` .. Please help.

Comment: You can find the Unicode code point of `ô` by looking into a [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=ô) which will tell you that it is `U+00F4`. In Ruby, it means that you have to write `"\u00F4"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result.gsub("‘", "'")
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @kiplantt said, the following also works(just tested it)

```
puts result.gsub(/(\`)/, "\\'")
```